# Create a trigger in MYSQL using FK

Tags: mysql, triggers

I seek to insert the name of the team, avoiding the repetition of the clear record.
Later with your ID register the match with its markers.

Ex:

**My input data**

```
1, 'Team A', 'Team W', 0, 1, '12/02/2021'
2, 'Team B', 'Team x', 2, 1, '12/10/2021'
...
n, 'Team ??', 'Team ??', 3, 1, '14/12/2021'
```

Table Team

```
Team(1, 'Team A')
Tema(2, 'Team B')
Tema(3, 'Team W')
Tema(4, 'Team X')
```

Table Match

```
Matches(1, 1, 2, 0, 1, '12/02/2021')
Matches(2, 3, 2, 2, 1, '12/10/2021')
Matches(3, 4, 3, 3, 1, '14/12/2021')
```

But first, look for 'Team A' in the 'Teams' table to obtain ID 10, if there is no such team, register. The same would happen with 'Team W'.
Or you can enter the teams and then the matches table records.

My problem is that I can't remember how to do this because all the examples I see are with fields that this table has, but in this case they are FK not the data itself.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `searchFkTeam` Befor Insert ON `matches` FOR EACH ROW
begin
 SET xteam = 'Team W'
 INSERT INTO team (name) VALUES (xteam)
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM teams WHERE name=xteam
 );
end;
DELIMITER ;
```

The declaration of the variable does not know how to do it because said field `new.team` there are no matches in the table, there is its FK

Table Team

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Team 1 |
| 2 | Team 2 |
| 3 | Team 3 |

Table Macthes (**Expected result**)

| idP | Team_A | Team_B | Goal_A | Goal_B | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 11/10/2021 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 12/10/2021 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 13/10/2021 |

P.S .: I hope I have explained myself well and thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> -- create tables
> CREATE TABLE teams (team_name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY);
> CREATE TABLE matches (team_1 VARCHAR(255),
>                       team_2 VARCHAR(255),
>                       match_date DATE,
>                       PRIMARY KEY (team_1, team_2, match_date),
>                       FOREIGN KEY (team_1) REFERENCES teams (team_name),
>                       FOREIGN KEY (team_2) REFERENCES teams (team_name)
>                       );
> ```

> ```
> -- create triggers which adds non-existent teams into teams table
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_matches
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON matches
> FOR EACH ROW
> INSERT IGNORE INTO teams VALUES (NEW.team_1), (NEW.team_2);
>
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_bu_matches
> BEFORE UPDATE
> ON matches
> FOR EACH ROW
> INSERT IGNORE INTO teams VALUES (NEW.team_1), (NEW.team_2);
> ```

> ```
> -- proceed matches data
> INSERT INTO matches VALUES 
> ('Team 1', 'Team 2', '2021-05-01'), -- insert teams 1 and 2
> ('Team 1', 'Team 3', '2021-05-02'), -- insert team 3
> ('Team 2', 'Team 4', '2021-05-03'), -- insert team 4
> ('Team 3', 'Team 4', '2021-05-04'); -- insert none
>
> UPDATE matches
> SET team_1 = 'Team 5', team_2 = 'Team 1' -- insert team 5
> WHERE match_date = '2021-05-04';
>
> -- check the result
> SELECT * FROM teams;
> SELECT * FROM matches;
> ```
>
> | team_name |
> | --- |
> | Team 1 |
> | Team 2 |
> | Team 3 |
> | Team 4 |
> | Team 5 |
>
> | team_1 | team_2 | match_date |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Team 5 | Team 1 | 2021-05-04 |
> | Team 1 | Team 2 | 2021-05-01 |
> | Team 1 | Team 3 | 2021-05-02 |
> | Team 2 | Team 4 | 2021-05-03 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9285659a17e5650b7e0dcf9c2a3c6bdd)*

Comment: But in the matches table I only need the team IDs not their name
instead of varchar (`team_1 VARCHAR(255), team_2 VARCHAR(255)`), it would be INT (`team_1 INT, team_2 INT`)
because using two triggers and an update

Comment: Int by its ID in the table Teams(id, name).  db <> fiddle that interesting did not know.   mm and I do not understand why to insert Team 5, but in principle it does not exist

Comment: @Cristian Create a fidlle like one in the answer but with your structures and data. Show INSERT query and desired final data state.

Comment: I have added a couple of tables I hope it is better understood @akina

Comment: @Cristian Please do what I asked, not what you imagined.